# Viper config file found on dev but not on production using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, viper-go

In normal development (included build binary) go finds the `config.yaml` file, but in production, when using a `Dockerfile` image, it does not.

My project folder is:

```
|-cmd
   |- server
     |- main.go
     |- server (executable when built)
|-config
   |-config.yaml
   |-config.go
```

config.go is:

```golang
func readConfigFile(viperConfig ViperConfig) {
    // Set default values if nil
    if viperConfig.ConfigName == "" {
        viperConfig.ConfigName = "config"
    }
    if viperConfig.ConfigType == "" {
        viperConfig.ConfigType = "yaml"
    }
    if viperConfig.ConfigAddPath == "" {
        // main execute it, so it's path is relative to who execute it.
        viperConfig.ConfigAddPath = "../../config"
    }
    // Read the config
    viper.SetConfigName(viperConfig.ConfigName)
    viper.SetConfigType(viperConfig.ConfigType)
    // This path is from main
    viper.AddConfigPath(viperConfig.ConfigAddPath)

    err := viper.ReadInConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN go build -o ./cmd/server/server ./cmd/server/main.go

FROM alpine AS final

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /app/cmd/server/server ./cmd/server/
COPY --from=base /app/config/config.yaml ./config/

CMD [ "./cmd/server/server" ]
```

And the error (panic) displayed when running the container from that built image is:

```
2021/05/12 18:08:32 Config File "config" Not Found in "[/config]"
```

How can I point to `/app/config/config.yaml` where the config file resides?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [viper docs](https://github.com/spf13/viper#establishing-defaults) you can add multiple search paths for configs by calling `viper.AddConfigPath` multiple times.

So try:

```
viper.AddConfigPath(viperConfig.ConfigAddPath)
viper.AddConfigPath("/app/config") // <- to work with Dockerfile setup
```

Comment: Will this not cause error in local environment if "/app/config" doesn't exist?

Comment: @insanely_sin They are merely hints for where Viper should look for configs. If not found it'll move on.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can add this command in Docker file.

- `src >>cmd >> api`

```
COPY --from=build-env /app/src/cmd/api /app/
```

Answer (score 0):

u try it.

```
CMD [".cmd/server/server", "--config-source=file","--config-file=config/config_dev.yml"]
```